# Creating a complicated algebra function

Tags: javascript, string, function, algebra

Doing an assignment for my JavaScript class that requires me to create a function that adds every other index starting with the first and subtracting all the indexes not previously added and produces the sum. I believe the function below should work but it seems to return undefined.

```
function questionSix(){
let result = 0;
for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++){
  if(i == 0){
    result += arguments[i];
  }else{
    if(i % 2 != 0){
      result += arguments[i];
      }
    if(i % 2 == 0){
    result -= arguments[i];
      }

  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you aren't returning anything (there is no return statement in your code) :

```js
    function questionSix(){
      let result = 0;
      for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        if(i == 0){
          result += arguments[i];
        }else{
          if(i % 2 != 0){
            result += arguments[i];
          }
          if(i % 2 == 0){
            result -= arguments[i];
          }
    
        }
      }
      return result;
    }
    console.log(questionSix(1,6,5,7,8,9,9,8,4,5));
```

However, it looks like your code isn't doing exactly what it should, here's a solution to your problem :

```js
function questionSix(){
  let result = 0; // the sum
  let array = []; // the numbers added
  for(let i = 0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
      // was the number added ?
      if(array.indexOf(i) > -1){ // Yes
        result += arguments[i]; // add it to the sum
      }else{ // No
        result -= arguments[i]; // subtract it from the sum
        array.push(arguments[i]); // add it to the array
      }
  }
  return result; // return the sum
}
console.log(questionSix(1,6,5,7,8,9,9,8,4,5));
```

Comment: Wow silly me, forgot it for only that one lol
Thanks so much :)

Answer (score 0):

#### You haven't included a "return" statement

The clue to this (apart from there being no `return` statement!) is that you start with a `result=0` statement, and yet you are receiving `undefined`.

#### You don't have to do a special case for i==0

When i==0,  i % 2 will equal 0, so the "inner" if-then-else will do the job adequately, without the `if (i==0)` segment.

#### Swap the += and -=

However I wonder whether you have reversed the `+=` and `-=` ? You want to add the 0th and all even-indexed values, don't you? And subtract the odd ones?